# Primefaces fileUpload - Which event for ajax call

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.3 and I want to do an ajax call when I upload my file

```
<p:fileUpload 
    id="fileUp"
    fileUploadListener="#{carEditDocumentController.handleFileUpload}"
    label="#{msg['document.selectDocument']}"
    auto="true"
    required="true"
    requiredMessage="#{msg['error.required']}"
    mode="advanced"
    skinSimple="true"                                       
    update="carDocumentNewName">
    <p:ajax listener="#{carEditDocumentController.checkDocument()}" event="???" update="carDocumentError"/>
</p:fileUpload>
```

Which event do I need to execute the listener when I upload my file?

Thank you.

Comment: See page 212 in the documentation... Something about a fileUploadListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any event for that. But I believe there are 2 other options:

1. Just call checkDocument() from the fileUploadListener.
2. Call a remoteCommand in oncomplete:

   ```
   <p:fileUpload ... oncomplete="rc()" />
   <p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="carDocumentError" actionListener="#{carEditDocumentController.checkDocument()}" />
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a solution and it's not possible to put a <p:ajax > like this. I simply add my function checkDocument() in the function called by the fileUploadListener