# How to enable a p:commandButton when select (but not send) a file in p:fileupload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with primefaces `commandButton` and `fileupload`.
I need to enable a `commandButton` when a file is select (but not upload) by the user through primefaces `fileupload` but i don't know how to detect that the file has been selected.

My code is:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formCrearPanel2">

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%">

        <h:outputText value="#{messages['listado.LOGO']}" />
        <p:fileUpload id="fileUploadCrear" widgetVar="fileUploadCrearWV" 
            fileUploadListener="#{listadoPlataformas.subidaImagenCrear}" 
            label="#{messages['comun.SELECCIONAR']}" sizeLimit="1048576" fileLimit="1"
            invalidSizeMessage="#{messages['comun.IMAGE.SIZE']}" 
            update="formularioPrincipal:listadoPlataformas formularioPrincipal:growl" 
            fileLimitMessage="#{messages['comun.IMAGE.FILE_LIMIT']}"  previewWidth="160">

        </p:fileUpload>

    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:panelGrid columns="3" style="width:100%; text-align:center;">

        <p:commandButton value="#{messages['comun.ACEPTAR']}"
            id="crearPlataformaAceptar_2" widgetVar="crearPlataformaAceptarWV_2" ajax="true" onclick="PF('fileUploadCrearWV').upload();"
            update="formularioPrincipal:listadoPlataformas formularioPrincipal:growl" 
            actionListener="#{listadoPlataformas.nothing}" disabled="true"/>


    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

I use

- Primefaces 6.2 - JDK 11 - JSF 2.2.19

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primefaces fileUpload - Which event for ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206378/primefaces-fileupload-which-event-for-ajax-call)

Comment: Maybe you could use `valueChangeListener`?

Comment: @Eehol not the same. Your post refers to a event when the file is upload and my question is about the event whe the file is select but not upload it.

Comment: @OscarPérez not works, when i select the file, the `valueChangeListener` is not called

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016651/check-whether-a-file-has-been-chosen-in-pfileupload?rq=1